# How can I schedule a periodic task once in every 3 days in django celery crontab?

Tags: python, django, cron, celery, celerybeat

Need to schedule a task every 3 days celery scheduler in django.
I have found the scheduling of different cases such as to schedule a task on minutely, hourly, daily, on-weekdays basis, but I could not find my requirement in the documentation of celery.
Does anyone know about this?

Comment: IMHO you can't set such period because the closest will be to use day of month, but some months have 30 days, some 31, some 28/29. Make this check if program and set it to run every day.